# Force 200 (cached)

Tags: http, caching, cache-control

I'm looking for a way to force my index HTML page to be cached in the browser with a response of `200 (cached)` rather than a normal `200` or `304` response.

This question is very similar to [Nginx - "force" 200 cache response instead of 304](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797302/nginx-force-200-cache-response-instead-of-304).

**What I have tried:**

I have tried sending these headers from my server:

```
Expires: (some date in the future)
Cache-Control: public
Pragma: public
```

Or:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
```

But neither of these get the result I need.

**Example site with working HTTP caching:**

https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/

On first load of the Mozilla website, everything is returned with a standard 200 response. On a refresh, all of the resources are loaded through the local cache (and the browser network tab shows a `200 (cached)` message).

The index page is sometimes loaded with a `200 OK` or `304`.

[image: Mozilla screenshot]

I want to know if it is possible to get my index page to load from the browser cache like the resources are on the Mozilla webpage. If it is possible, how can this be done?

Comment: 200 is 200, what do you mean by 200 (cached)? How did you determine it’s not being cached?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `200` and `200 (cached)` are not the same thing. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665097

Comment: That talks about some plugin that shows states like that. It’s still 200 in HTTP terms.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm asking if there is a way for me to force caching without making a request to the server in the first place, by using response headers. I've seen that a browser can do that with HTTP caching. The browser tends to display `200 (cached)` in this case.

Comment: Force? No. Suggest? Yes, with the headers you’ve used. But you haven’t explained what isn’t working and you’ve determined this

Comment: I have updated the question to have more thorough information (and an example).